# Android. How to access a class from another file to MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I created a separate java class called SetIP.java with just a simple print:

```
package com.myname.appname;

import android.util.Log;

public class SetIP {

    public void hello(){
        Log.d("System", "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity I try to call it by:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SetIP setip = new SetIP();
    setip.hello();
   // OnCreate and Stuff
}
```

But the error said cannot resolve symbol 'Hello'. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Your `setip.hello()` is not in a method of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Did you import your SetIp class at the top of your MainActivity?

Comment: @SammyT `package com.myname.appname;` at the beginning of `SetIP `strongly suggests both classes are in the default package.  If that's true, importing `SetIP` in `MainActivity` is not necessary.

Comment: However, calling `setip.hello()` directly in the body of `MainActivity` like that will definitely cause a compiler error.  It should be called inside a method, like `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { setip.hello(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call a method of an object of any of the classes on the fly as you are calling now, As you told your `// OnCreate and Stuff` is below than your object's method call.

It has to be inside constructor or some methods, Like here

```
SetIP setip = new SetIP();
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setip.hello();
   }
```

**OR**

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SetIP setip = new SetIP();
      setip.hello();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Make so much sense. !

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it in onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SetIP setip = new SetIP();
    setip.hello();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate SetIP as global variable to MainActivity, but calling the function should still resides within a function of MainActivity. One example is to put this in onCreate activity as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SetIP setip = new SetIP();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setip.hello();
    }

    // Other Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      SetIP setip = new SetIP();
      setip.hello();
   }

   // Other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change only method is static like

```
public class SetIP {    
    public static void hello(){
        Log.d("System", "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Try this work.

Comment: Did you try it yourself? (Hint:  `hello()` can be a static method indeed, but it won't solve the problem)

Comment: SetIP.hello() try this, no need to create object of the class you can access direct method

Comment: Yeah you can call static methods without instantiating an object.  Again - it doesn't solve the problem.  You still can't call `SetIP.hello()` from the class body like that, you'll need to call it from a method. Please, take your own advise, and try it.